# Firestore .set({}) sometimes doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore is working correctly for everything, but there is one exception.
I am trying to build simple app that tracks your amount of food in your fridge.
You can simply add and remove 1 piece at the time.
I wanted to delete key and its value from map of food when it's quantity is equal to 0 (obviously)

**Here is my code that removes 1 from food quantity**

First I get data from Firestore about food that is already in fridge, and then check if quantity is equal to 1 so it's key and value should be removed and not displayed in app. Then I simply update food in Firestore.

```
Map<String, dynamic> foodInFridge = await getDataFromFirestore('families', familyID, 'food');
    foodInFridge[foodName]['quantity'] == 1? foodInFridge.remove(foodName) : foodInFridge[foodName]['quantity'] -= 1;
    print(foodInFridge);
await _db.collection('families').doc(familyID).set({
      'food':foodInFridge
    }, SetOptions(merge : true));
```

It works great - it removes 1 piece and updates quantity in Firestore, until there is 1 left and it starts bugging.
print(foodInFridge) prints map without key and value, but it doesn't update in Firestore

**Example situation:**
I have 1 Beef and 1 Egg. I remove 1 Beef and this is what I get printed from print(foodInFridge):
`{Egg: {quantity: 1, month: 12, year: 2023}}` - you see that it updates correctly in code, but it doesn't update in Firestore and app, it still remains in it as `{Egg: {quantity: 1, month: 12, year: 2023}, Beef: {quantity: 1, month: 12, year: 2023}}`

**But the code works well if there is only 1 food**
I have 1 Egg. I remove it, print(foodInFridge) gives me empty map and this time it updates in Firestore and app so it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to how the `set()` operation works with `merge: true`. As noted in the documentation, the [merge option will cause the database to merge new data with existing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

So if your database has existing data,

```
{"food":{"egg":{"quantity":2},"beef":{"quantity":1}}}
```

And then you attempt to delete "beef" by merging in

```
{"food":{"egg":{"quantity":2}}}
```

Then Firestore will keep what is already in the document for "beef", so you don't see any change to "beef".

In the case where you're deleting the last item in your map, you are passing in

```
{"food":{}}
```

The [documentation states that passing in an empty map will overwrite the entire map field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). So this is also working as expected.

For your use case, it would be better to use [`FieldValue.increment(-1)`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/increment.html) and [`FieldValue.delete()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/delete.html). These field values can be used to modify a single field with `update(...)` or `set(...)`. I like `update()` for these use cases because you can use dot notation to specify the nested field to update.

Using `update()`, you could delete with:

```
await _db.collection('families').doc(familyID).update({'food.egg': FieldValue.delete()});
```

And you could decrement with:

```
await _db.collection('families').doc(familyID).update({'food.egg.quantity': FieldValue.increment(-1)});
```